# How to merge grouped records into one row in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

How can I merge grouped records (byt SurvId) into one single row where Column `Mode` is part of the column name?

This

```
ID  SurvId   Mode            A       B  
---------------------------------------
1   1        Unrestricted    1       3
2   1        Restricted      5       2 
3   2        Unrestricted    6       4
4   2        Restricted      4       1
```

Into this

```
SurvId   UnrestictedA   UnrestrictedB   RestrictedA   RestrictedB
------------------------------------------------------------
1        1              3               5             2
2        6              4               4             1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select survid,
       max(case when mode = 'Unrestricted' then A end) as unrestricted_a,
       max(case when mode = 'Restricted' then A end) as restricted_a,
       max(case when mode = 'Unrestricted' then B end) as unrestricted_b,
       max(case when mode = 'Restricted' then B end) as restricted_b
from t
group by survid;
```

Comment: Incredible response time :o

Comment: Because this is such a frequently asked question, @DiPix ; pretty sure Gordon has a macro for this one (along with many others).

Comment: One more question 
`MAX(IIF([Mode] = 'Unrestricted', [A], NULL)) AS UnrestrictedA` will work the same?

Comment: @DiPix . . . You can use `IIF()` if -- for some reason -- you want to avoid the **standard** and more powerful `CASE` expression.

Comment: Why it is more powerful? Isn't just different syntax but with the same result? `IIF()` seems a shorter version.

Comment: @DiPix . . . `IIF()` is bepoke syntax for Microsoft products.  `CASE` does not require an `ELSE` clause.  It can handle multiple conditions.  It has a "searched" syntax for constants.  Why bother learning to use something else that is less powerful, versatile, and not standard?